# Jordan-Hölder Theorem for Modules and Euler-Poincaré Mappings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In Serge Lang’s *Algebra*, he asserts that

> In the language of Euler characteristics, the Jordan-Hölder theorem can be reformulated as follows:
> **Theorem 8.1.** *Let $\varphi$ be a rule which to each simple module associates an element of a commutative group $\Gamma$, and such that if $M \approx M’$ then $\varphi (M) = \varphi (M’)$. Then $\varphi$ has a unique extension to an Euler-Poincaré mapping defined on all modules of finite length.*

A module of finite length is a module $M$ that admits a sequence $M \supset ... \supset M_r = 0$ such that $M_i/M_{i+1}$ is simple (or $M = 0$.) He then gives the following proof:

> Given a simple filtration $M \supset ... \supset M_r = 0$ we define $\varphi (M) = \sum_{1}^{r-1} \varphi (M_i/M_{i+1})$. The Jordan-Hölder theorem shows immediately that this is well defined, and that this extension of $\varphi$ is an Euler-Poincaré map.

First, I don't see why $\varphi$ is necessarily an Euler-Poincaré map. Second, if Theorem 8.1 is a reformulation of the Jordan-Hölder theorem, why does it imply the Jordan-Hölder theorem?